# solve_bvp not giving the correct solution

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, ode

I am trying to solve a boundary value problem that I know will have a Bessel-like shape. My conditions are u[0]=1,u[40]=v[0]=v[40]=0. However, for U, it is giving me a flat line with x=1. Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong? Thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```
#Parameters
mu=0
eta = 1 #0.3
Dlt= 0.1 #.5
lbd= -1
alp= 1
Vz=1 

def dU_dx(x, U):
    # Let's try to make U as vector such that u=U[0],y=U[1],v=U[2] and z=U[3].
    #This function should return [u',y',v', z']
    
    return [U[1], 
            lbd*Dlt*U[2]+alp*(U[3]+U[2]/x)+(Vz-mu)*U[0] - U[1]*(1/x),
            U[3],
            (-lbd*Dlt*U[0]-alp*(U[1])+(-Vz-mu)*U[2] -U[3]*(1/x)+1/x**2*U[2])/eta]

def bc1(ya1,yb1):

    return np.array([ya1[0]-1,yb1[0],ya1[1],yb1[1]-0.5])

#Define the initial mesh with 5 nodes:

x = np.linspace(0, 40, 5) #(0, 1, 10)

#This problem is known to have two solutions. To obtain both of them, we use two different initial guesses for y. We denote them by subscripts a and b.

U = np.zeros((4, x.size))

U[0] = 1
U[1] = 0
U[2] = 0
U[3] = 0.5

#Now we are ready to run the solver.

from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp

res_a = solve_bvp(dU_dx, bc1, x, U)

#Let’s plot the two found solutions. We take an advantage of having the solution in a spline form to produce a smooth plot.

x_plot = np.linspace(10**-6, 40, 1000)

y_plot_a = res_a.sol(x_plot)[0]
y_plot_b = res_a.sol(x_plot)[2]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x_plot, y_plot_a, label='y_a')
plt.plot(x_plot, y_plot_b, label='y_b')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

My code is based on an example from scipy.integrate.solve_bvp site.

I have warnings such as:

> RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
>
> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
>
> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the full traceback (which you should have included)

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  lbd * Dlt * U[2]  + alp * (U[3] + U[2] / x) + (Vz - mu) * U[0] - U[1] * (1 / x),
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  lbd * Dlt * U[2]  + alp * (U[3] + U[2] / x) + (Vz - mu) * U[0] - U[1] * (1 / x),
...
```

gives you the perfect pointer: *divide by zero encountered in true_divide* (hint: `... / x`).

Replace

```
x = np.linspace(0, 40, 5)
```

with

```
x = np.linspace(1, 40, 5)
```

and see what happens when you don't try to divide by 0.

Comment: Oh man! Thank you so much! Sorry, I am new in Python.

Comment: I almost got what I wanted, but in the original graph, my y_plot_b should start from zero and go downwards. It's going up. Any clue if that could be a computational problem? This was happening also when I tried to compute in mathematica, so I am not sure.

Comment: @BrunaMendonça Sorry, I don't know the math involved here, so it's hard to say. If you get the same effect in mathematica then I would suspect it's due to your setup.